# Bluetooth serial connection for Iphone app

Tags: ios, iphone, bluetooth, mfi

I have a general question about using bluetooth in apps. I'm doing a college program that involves communicating with a serial bluetooth device from a phone. I originally found that Iphone apps are easier to create (I have C/C++ but no java, hence the lean away from android) but Ive came across several posts about having to register with MFI in order to use bluetooth serial. Can college students do this as a once off basis for one app? Is it worthwhile or expensive?
Any help'd be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to choose the bluetooth device first and know about its category i.e BLE or Classic. For BLE you can use Corebluetooth and for Classic one you have to use MFI. Yes MFI will be paid and expensive too. Refer to developer site for this and also this question.

[iPhone bluetooth and "Made for iPod"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6524466/iphone-bluetooth-and-made-for-ipod?rq=1)

https://mfi.apple.com/MFiWeb/enroll.action.

Hope this helps.